# Set a dropdown to active or not using a layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, drop-down-menu, twig

I'm actually using Symfony framework 3, so I use twig to render my page and i'm using a 'general' layout named layout.html.twig :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        {% block head %}
            <meta charset='utf-8'>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>{% block title %} AcreatMailing {% endblock title %}</title>
            {% block js_head %}
                <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/components/MDBootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js') }}"></script>
            {% endblock js_head %}
            {% block stylesheet %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
                <link href="{{ asset('/bundles/front/css/style.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
            {% endblock stylesheet %}
        {% endblock head %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1 col-sm-1">
                        <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class="col-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 offset-lg-2" id="spanSearch">
                        <h4><span class="badge indigo hide">{# block badge_research %}{% endblock #}</span></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 offset-2 col-sm-2 offset-sm-3 col-md-2 offset-md-3 col-lg-2 offset-lg-3">
                        <div class="search d-inline pull-right">
                            <a href="#" onclick="showAndHide()" id='icon' ><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <form class="form-inline waves-effect waves-light" id="form">
                                <input class="form-control tags" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeydown="keyDown()">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    !-->
                    <div class="col-7 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 offset-lg-5">
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right downMenu inline">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown btn-group">
                                <a class="nav-link" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %} <img src="{{ asset('/Image/contact.png') }}" class="img-circle" width="50" height="50"> {% else %} {{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.account'|trans }} {% endif %}</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu top dropdown" no-escape aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                    <div class="card">
                                        <div class="card-block">
                                            <div class="container-fuild">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-3">
                                                        <img src="{{ asset('/Image/contact.png') }}" class="img-circle" width="200" height="112">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-9">
                                                        {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                                                            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}" class="dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.myaccount'|trans }}</a>
                                                            <a href="{{ path('fos_user_change_password') }}" class="dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.changepassword'|trans }}</a>
                                                            {% if is_granted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN') %}
                                                                <a href="{{ path('front_index', {'account': '_exit'}) }}" class="dropdown-item">{{'acreat.mailing.admin.impersonalisation'|trans}}</a>
                                                            {% endif %}
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                                                        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}" class="btn btn-block acreatRed dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.logout'|trans }}</a>
                                                        {% else %}
                                                        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}" class="btn btn-block acreatRed dropdown-item">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.login'|trans }}</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="search d-inline inline pull-right">
                            <a href="#" onclick="showAndHide()" id='icon' ><i class="fa fa-search fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                            <form class="form-inline waves-effect waves-light" id="form">
                                <input class="form-control tags inline" id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search" onkeydown="keyDown()">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline pull-right spanSearch">
                            <h5>{% block badge_research %}{% endblock %}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                {% block navbar %}
                    <div class="sidebar blue-grey darken-4 no-escape" id="navbar">
                        <div class="user-box no-escape">
                            <a class="logo no-escape" href="/" title="Retour à l'accueil">
                                <img src ="https://www.acreat.com/sites/acreat.com/themes/acreat/images/logo.png" class="img-fluid text-center no-escape"></img>
                            </a>
                            <h5 class="text-center">{{ 'acreat.mailing.title.website'|trans }}</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group panel no-escape" aria-expanded="true">
                            <a href="/" id="dashboard" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-dashboard margin-right"></i> <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.dashboard'|trans }}</span> </a>
                            <a href="#menu0" class="list-group-item no-escape arrowContainer" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-tasks margin-right"></i><span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.inbox'|trans }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="wrapperArrow"></i></span></a>
                            <div class="collapse show no-escape" id="menu0">
                                <a href="/message/template/{{app.user.id}}" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="addmessage" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.addmessage'|trans }}</span>
                                </a>
                                {%- set numberNotSent = doctrine.createQueryBuilder().select('COUNT(u.id)').from('CoreBundle:Message', 'u').where("u.status !='COMPLETED'")
                                .andWhere("u.account = " ~ app.user.id).andWhere("u.status !='SUBMITTED'").getQuery().getResult() -%}
                                <a href="/message/viewNotSent" class="list-group-item no-escape" data-parent="#sidebar" id="viewNotSent" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span class="fixed-witdh">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.messagenotsent'|trans }}</span>
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ numberNotSent[0][1] }}</span>
                                </a>
                                {%- set numberSent = doctrine.createQueryBuilder().select('COUNT(u.id)').from('CoreBundle:Message', 'u').where("u.status ='COMPLETED'")
                                .andWhere("u.account = " ~ app.user.id).getQuery().getResult() -%}
                                <a href="/message/viewSent" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="viewSent" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span class="fixed-witdh">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.messagesent'|trans }}</span>
                                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">{{ numberSent[0][1] }}</span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="/message/viewDraft" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="draft" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true">
                                    <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.draft'|trans }}</span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <a href="/mailinglist/view" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="listview" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-list margin-right"></i> <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.mailinglist'|trans }}</span> </a>
                            <a href="/member/view" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="memberview" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false" ><i class="fa fa-users margin-right"></i> <span>{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.member'|trans }}</span></a>
                            {%- if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') -%}
                                <div id="adminBottom" class="no-escape">
                                    <a href="#menu4" class="list-group-item no-escape bottom arrowContainer2" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-envelope margin-right"></i> <span >{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administration'|trans }}<i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="wrapperArrow2"></i></span></a>
                                    <div class="collapse show no-escape" id="menu4">
                                        <a href="/admin/mailinglist" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="adminlist" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationlist'|trans }}</a>
                                        <a href="/admin/account/view" class="list-group-item no-escape" id='adminaccount' data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationaccount'|trans }}</a>
                                        <a href="/admin/message" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="adminmessage" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationnewsletter'|trans }}</a>
                                        <a href="/admin/parameters" class="list-group-item no-escape" id="adminparameters" data-parent="#menu4">{{ 'acreat.mailing.nav.administrationparameters'|trans }}</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            {%- endif -%}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endblock navbar %}
            {%- endif -%}
            <div id="content">
                {% block body %}
                        {%- if app.user == false -%}
                            <main class="col-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                        {%- else -%}
                            <main class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 ">
                        {%- endif -%}
                            {% block flashmessage %}
                                {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        {{ flashMessage }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('fail') %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        {{ flashMessage }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
                                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                        {{ flashMessage }}
                                    </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endblock flashmessage %}
                            {% block main %}
                                {%- block breadcrumb -%}{%- endblock -%}
                                <section></section>
                                {%- block confirmation -%}{%- endblock -%}
                            {% endblock main %}
                            {% block fos_user_content %}
                            {% endblock fos_user_content%}
                        </main>
                {% endblock body %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
{% block footer %}
    {% block footer_javascript %}
        <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/components/MDBootstrap/js/tether.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('bundles/front/components/moment/min/moment.min.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/components/MDBootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
        <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/components/MDBootstrap/js/mdb.min.js') }}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js') }}"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/js/libraries.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/bundles/front/js/acreatmailingfront.min.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock footer_javascript %}
{% endblock footer %}
</html>
```

And i would like to know if there is any solution more simple that use a twig if tag like :

```
    <a href="#" class="...{% if menu1 is not defined %} collapsed {% endif %}>...</a>
```

Because I can't set it with jQuery or javascript when the user decide to show or hide this menu because my layout is regenerate when I reload my page or when I change my page...

If anyone have an idea, let me know !

**[EDIT]**
Clearer question : 
how can i change the class of my item according to the comportement of the user, if he clicked to drop the menu down, then let the menu down as long as he clicked another time

Thanks in advance !

Comment: don't understand the question ... you want to know if what you wrote works in twig ?

Comment: No, i want to know is there is an alternative to this, how can i change the class of my item according to the comportement of the user, if he clicked to drop the menu down, then let the menu down as long as he clicked another time.